# Javascript, serialport can't output numbers, just ascii

Tags: javascript, serial-port, node-serialport

so I want my program to pass an int into the serialport, but javascript makes all numbers floats, that is bad.
even more if i try

```
sp.write(255)//outputs 0x080000010000000000000000020000
sp.write(256)//outputs infinitely
```

I hooked it up to a bus pirate so I could check the output

if I convert numbers to a hex string then the serialport sends out the char equivalent of my number, this is also bad.

```
var hex=(0xFF).toString(8);
sp.write(hex); //out=0x333737  which is 377=>0x0255 oh and not 8 bits...
hex=(0xFF).toString(16);
sp.write(hex); //out=0x6666  which is FF so at least that one makes some sense
hex=0b10101010; // error... binary does work when i run javascript in html though
```

but it does output asci characters so that i get the proper hex on the other side

ive tried

```
function hex2a(hexx) {
var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
    str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
return str;
}
```

but for that 0xff=>0x2505

and ive also tried

```
hex = String.fromCharCode(hex)
```

which works perfectly up to 127, after that it is 2 bytes with either a 194 or 195 in first byte

I need to be able to send 8 bytes of integer bit data to an arduino.

Comment: The documentation for [sp.write](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport#user-content-write-buffer-callback) says it accepts a buffer or array of bytes or a string. What is supposed to happen when sending an "int of determinate length"? You've lost me.

Comment: but buffer objects have functions for dealing with ints, https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readintle_offset_bytelength_noassert. basically I have a black box (its an arduino but someone else is programming it) I need to send this box 8 bytes of integer data, each refering to the state data of a controller. at this point though I would be willing to believe that serialport was literally not designed to send actual numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var buffer = new Buffer([ 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]);
```

which works for any value between 0 and 255.

thanks to Traktor53 for point out it is a buffer object
and to https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers
for confirming how to consruct a Buffer